# Points inside rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Maybe someone can help with this problem:
Inside a rectangle with sides 4 and 5 are given six points. Prove that the distance
between some two points is less than 3. Thanks.

Comment: A possible approach: find a way to split the rectangle into five pieces such that if there are two points in the same piece then they can't be more than three units apart.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider that the distances among the six points are the furthest if they are equally spaced inside the rectangle, as depicted in the diagram. Let the equal distance be $d$ and establish,

$$d^2 = 2^2 + \left(\frac{5-d}{2}\right)^2$$

Then, solve for $d$ to verify $d<3$.

Edit: As kindly pointed out by @David K below, there is yet a better configuration that has 4 on the corners and the other 2 along the vertical center line. The largest distance is then given by,

$$d^2=2.5^2+(4-d)^2/4$$

Comment: You can get a larger minimum distance between points by putting four in the corners and two along the vertical center line. So a method like this must not only compute the distance in a configuration, it must also show that its configuration is optimal.

Comment: yeah, you’re right